# Is there a XSD file for MBeans

Tags: java, xsd, jmx, mbeans

I am working on a JMX project and for the purpose of exposing the MBean's attributes and Operations of all the MBeans in my project, I wanted to write an API. For this I needed MBean xsd file with proper namespaces from the provider so that I can use JAXB or XMLBeans to generate java classes for them. I tried google but could only find DTD files or non-standard XSD file without proper namesapces.

Is there a standard XSD available which I can use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Commons Modeler](http://commons.apache.org/modeler/) uses an XML descriptor to do this. However, they do not implement a schema, but they do have a [DTD](http://commons.apache.org/dtds/mbeans-descriptors.dtd), which should be convertible to a schema for your own uses.

Comment: Ya I have this DTD. Before posting here I tried converting this DTD to XSD using toolings but the generated schema lacks namespaces. That's where the issue is. Both JAXB and XMLBeans use the targetNamespace and xml:ns attributes for binding the classes to their packages. When I use XMLBeans, the generated JAR file contains absurd package names like "noNamespace". Any idea how to deal with this issue?

Comment: I guess it is more of an XML issue than a JMX issue, per se. I suppose you could work up your own namespace enabled schema and use XSLT to convert down to a modeller compatible document.